# How to save aliases and metadata in shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, metadata, alias

Is there a way to save the aliases in a QGIS shapefile?

When I save the shapefile in a different name or open it in a different QGIS project the entered aliases have disappeared.  The same happens for metadata.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a bug I would call it a WAD (Work As Designed). The changes has to be saved as a project, if you want to persist the changes. You could add a [feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues?set_filter=1&tracker_id=2) to the QGIS development team ([some help](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#bugs-features-and-issues)) to get the alias and metadata saved in a QGIS Layer Style File (*.qml).

A side note: On of the strong things of qml-files is that if you name them same as the other files composing the shapefile, the setting would get loaded automatically, when you open the shapefile. A shotcut is saving the style as default.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, in 2021 aliases are still not among the many things saved in style files (.qml). It seems a little surprising, actually, since there is specifically an 'Attribute Forms' element on the list of style settings to copy/paste, save or load, and almost every other setting in Attribute Forms (Widgets, Default Values, etc) is included in it. Just aliases get left out.